# Cannot import app modules implementing Flask CLI

Tags: python, flask, command-line-interface

For some reason when I try to execute my custom command:

> flask create_user

I get an error whenever I try import anything from my src folder:

> File "/app/backend/flask_app/command.py", line 17, in seed_db
>       import src.models
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

```
/
    __init__.py
    command.py
    run.py
    src/
        __init__.py
        models/
            __init__.py
            user_model.py
```

> command.py

```
import click
from flask import Flask
from flask.cli import with_appcontext

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.cli.command()
@with_appcontext
def create_user():
    import src.models as models
    print("hello")

app.cli.add_command(seed_db)
```

Comment: and `__init__.py` is in the `src` directory? It's a bit unclear from the copied filetree.

Comment: I've a bit of a problem reading your tree, but I think the `__init__.py` file in the `src/` directory is missing as mentioned before by @Joost

Comment: @Joost yes, you are correct. The __init__.py is in the src directory. I fixed the tree to make it more clear.

Comment: Where is the command.py file in the tree structure? is at the same level of src folder or is inside it?

Comment: @AntonioRomano fixed the tree - command.py in the root directory of the tree

Comment: @DominiqueBarton I fixed the tree. See my latest comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

I had to delete the root dir `__init__.py` file.

I found this answer from the famous Miguel Grinberg:

https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky/issues/310#issuecomment-340641813

> These files (`__init__.py`) make python believe the main directory of the package is one directory above, so that is the directory that is added to the Python path. Usually you want your top-level directory to not be a Python package, so that the current directory goes to the path.

__

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of python way of import modules, not about Flask command.

Since **command.py** file is at the same level of the **models** folder you can just write:

```
import models.user_models as users
```

After that you can acces the **user_models** module from **users** reference:

```
import models.user_models as users
users.some_function_name()
```

Comment: Sorry, I believe I had the wrong tree structure. Apologies on the error. The command.py is not on the same level as models, it's in the app root directory. `models` is in the `src` directory.

Comment: I've tried putting the `command.py` in the same level of the `models` dir, and the solution you provided doesn't work either. Same error.